# Change elements in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, max

Okay so i´ve got this list which is composed of a smaller lists of tuples:

```
cards=[[(0, 0), (0, 0)], [(6, '♥'), (6, '♦')], [(7, '♥'), (7, '♦')], [(7, '♥'), (7, '♦')], [(7, '♥'), (7, '♦')]]
```

My problem is i want to change the smaller lists into `[[(0, 0), (0, 0)]]` so my program ignores them, how could i make it that only the bigger tuples stay there?

the expected output should be this one:

```
cards=[[(0, 0), (0, 0)],[(0, 0), (0, 0)], [(7, '♥'), (7, '♦')], [(7, '♥'), (7, '♦')], [(7, '♥'), (7, '♦')]]
```

but for this question i dont need to know how to change the list of tuples into `[(0, 0), (0, 0)]` i just need to know how to discard the `[(6, '♥'), (6, '♦')]`

and the first `[(0, 0), (0, 0)]` is one card that has already been discarded, it may not always be like that, just for claryfying

Comment: What does **smaller** mean?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want to do. Please add sample input and expected output. Please [edit] your question and add all details.

Comment: by smaller i mean any list of tuples that hasnt got the max number, could be [(6,..),(6,..)] like this one or the number could be 3, 2 or 5, and if the max is bigger any number below that

Comment: More generally, do you want to replace the "smaller" elements of `cards[1:]` with `cards[0]`?

Comment: Does suit play any role in determine "smaller", or *just* the rank?

Comment: Can a sublist ever have tuples with different ranks, like `[(6, '♥'), (7, '♦')]`?

Comment: no, it could one be one pair of cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing values:

```
highest_pairs = list(filter(lambda x: x == max(cards), cards))
```

Replacing values:

```
cards = [item if item in highest_pairs else [(0,0), (0,0)] for item in cards]
```